# rodeo python path not getting set

Tags: pythonpath, rodeo

[image]

[image]

[image]

I installed anaconda but the envs folder is empty. So I gave the following 
`D:\sw\python\python.exe, D:\sw\Anaconda3\python.exe` in the textbox beside set path button but it didn't work.

User Environment variables of my computer

path:

[image]

System environment variables of my computer

path:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try setting the path without ".exe"

Comment: @Ben, Still it's not working :(

Comment: I uninstalled python from D: and then re installed in the default location and reset all the environment variables. Now it works :)